# pull last 5 minutes of syslog data (750mb) with tac combo sed/awk/grep/?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

Trying to pull the last 5 minutes of logs with (grep matches)

so i do a `tac syslog.log | sed / date -d "5 minutes ago"`

every line on the log shows this format

```
Jun 14 14:03:58  
Jul  3 08:04:35
```

so i really want to get the check of data from

```
Jul  4 08:12
Jul  4 08:17
```

i tried this method but KINDA works (though its still going through every day from this that 08:12: through 08:17: fits in)

```
e=""
for (( i = 5; i >= 0; i-- ))
do
    e='-e /'`date +\%R -d "-$i min"`':/p '$e; 
done

tac /var/log/syslog.log | sed -n $e
```

Comment: i think i almost got it with this

dt=$(date '+%b %e %H:%M:' -d '6 minutes ago'); tac var/log/routers.log | sed '/"$dt"/ q

Comment: Found out my syslog dumps false time info as each switch can be literally 30 seconds off or takes 20 seconds later to head to the syslog therefore it could miss logs after the time frame.

Answer (score 2):

```
e=""
for (( i = 5; i >= 0; i-- ))
do
    if [[ -z $e ]]
    then e=`date +\%R -d "-$i min"`
    else e=$e'\|'`date +\%R -d "-$i min"`
    fi
done
re=' \('$e'\):'
tac /var/log/syslog.log | sed -n -e "/$re/p" -e "/$re/!q"
```

This creates a single regular expression listing all the times from the last 5 minutes, connected with `\|`. It prints the lines that matches them. Then it uses the `!` modifier to quit on the first line that doesn't match the RE.

Comment: ohhhhh interesting im going to try this now

Comment: it fails on !q



-bash: !q": event not found

Comment: That's because you're doing it in an interactive shell, where `!` is used for history substitution. Put it in a script.

Comment: that method above actually just failed im going to try and add the date in front of it Jul 17

Comment: so i tried to add this


       then e=`date +\%b' '\%e' '\%R -d "-$i min"`
       else e=$e'\|'`date +\%b' '\%e' '\%R -d "-$i min"`
 

and it came out correct with the DAY fine but i think SED isnt liking the space

Comment: As long as you've put the `sed` arguments in double quotes, as in my script, it shouldn't mind the space.

Comment: so it comes out like this and doesnt grab anything Reason why i need it as it fails at the 00:00 time and then scans the syslog for the last day

Comment: OUTPUT that didnt work.

 \(Aug 28 06:29\|Aug 28 06:30\|Aug 28 06:31\|Aug 28 06:32\|Aug 28 06:33\|Aug 28 06:34\|Aug 28 06:35\):

Comment: You're missing the `\` before `(` and `)`. Did you remove that from the `re=` line? Put it back!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the format of the dates then why not do:

```
tac syslog.log | awk '/Jul  4 08:17/,/Jul  4 08:12/ { print } /Jul 4 08:11/ {exit}'
```

`/ .. /,/ .. /` is **regex range**. It will print everything in this range. So as soon as you see `/Jul 4 08:11/` on your line that would mean your 5 minutes window has been captured, you exit perusing the file.

Comment: i Switched to this one but now it fails and if theres nothing in the log say 08:11 then it fails and shows everything since the 2 days of the syslogs.... is there a way to put like a range on the {exit} of like 2 minutes

Comment: it might be overkill but the exit and if theres nothing at the beginning like nothing at 08:17 then it wont pull anything

Comment: thinking of doing this tac syslog.log | egrep "Aug 28 05:59|Aug 28 05:58|Aug 28 05:57|Aug 28 05:56|Aug 28 05:55"

Answer (score 0):

So it didnt really work for the above method But i think i got it to work

if i see this i added a RANGE for the {exit}

awk '/'"$dtnow"'/,/'"$dt6min"'/ { print } /'"$dt7min"'/,/'"$dt11min"'/ {exit}'

Seems to work im testing it again

Comment: its still failing it looks like

Answer (score 0):

OK Finally looks like it really works this time (where it exits after the hour using SED instead of awk finally got it to work running through some tests.

```
tac /var/log/syslog.log | sed -e "$( date -d '-1 hour -6 minutes' '+/^%b %e %H:/q;' 
   date -d '-1 day -6 minutes' '+/^%b %e /q;'
      date -d '-1 month -6 minutes' '+/^%b /q;'
for ((o=0;o<=5;o++)) do date -d "-$o minutes" '+/^%b %e %R:/p;'; done ; echo d)"
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if log entries begins from "May 14 11:41". Variable LASTMINUTES is used to set the last n minutes in the log:

```
cat log | awk 'BEGIN{ LASTMINUTES=30; for (L=0;L<=LASTMINUTES;L++) TAB[strftime("%b %d %H:%M",systime()-L*60)] } { if (substr($0,0,12) in TAB) print $0 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

To run the above script you need gawk which can be installed by:

```
apt-get install gawk
```

or

```
yum install gawk
```

Comment: You should make this a comment on whatever script you are talking about, so it is clear what you are saying. Answers are also meant to answer the original question, which this does not.